Why does my VBA Script fail to export the excel file from SAP?
I have an Excel Macro / VBA script which exports a table from SAP as Excel file. It then activates this new Excel file. Here is an excerpt from my code:
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = ""
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").contextMenu
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
filname = "Reuse_" & Date & Hour(Now) & ".xlsx"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxt[1]").Text = filname
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxt[1]").caretPosition = 7
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
Windows(filname).Activate

When I run it with the debugger step-by-step in VBA, this works. But when I run it as a whole, it breaks off, with two popup windows showing up. Note that the exported Excel file has not opened yet at this time (which I think is the very problem).
One VBA popup telling me

Runtime error '9': Index out of range

And one Excel popup telling me

Excel cannot perform the desired action because a dialog box is open

If I click on OK on the Excel popup and on 'Debugging' on the VBA popup, two things happen simultaneously:

The last line in the code above is highlighted, indicating that VBA can't find the exported file.
The desired Excel file immediately opens (alas, too late).

I tried adding actions in SAP or Excel before the activation of the exported file. But the file didn't open then, either (only in debugging mode). I also tried adding Application.Wait.

What's the reason that you need to activate the excel file? It will open up sooner or later anyway. Otherwise you need to understand this and adjust it to your needs. But, as you are a newbie, that will be very likely an almost impossible task. But, on the other hand, adding Application.Wait before the activate should be sufficient.

I need to activate it to copy content from it to another excel file. If it opened "sooner or later", my problem would be solved... It only opens when the script ends.
I tried Application.Wait. Doesn't work :(

In that case you need to understand the post I linked to. A timer is used to wait for the excel file to open. And then the code closes the file. You need to adjust that and instead of closing you do your stuff.

Thanks for your patience. I'm trying to understand and I looked at your link. The problem seems to be a different one since they are trying to close files. My problem is that they don't open in time.
The way I see it, time-related solutions won't work. When I run the code step-by-step with the debugger, the file opens within 1 second.

Sorry, but your guess is incorrect. You have this behaviour because you are in the debug mode. If you remove the line Windows(filname).Activate everything will run fine. The issue you have is that you would like to get a grab on the Excel file that  SAP opens asynchronously. The line Windows(filname).Activatejust after the lines which trigger the export will not find the file you refer to as it is too early. Application.Wait might help but I am not sure and it is  for sure not reliable. So, you have to use a timer as in the linked post.

As said in the comments you have this behaviour because you are in the debug mode. If you remove the line Windows(filname).Activate everything will run fine. The issue you have is that you would like to get a grab on the Excel file that SAP opens asynchronously. The line Windows(filname).Activate just after the lines which trigger the export will not find the file you refer to as it is too early.
Put the following code into a module
    Option Explicit
    
    
    #If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "User32" Alias _
                "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, _
                ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
                ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
                (ByVal lpsz As LongPtr, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As LongPtr
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
                (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal dwId As LongPtr, ByRef riid As GUID, _
                ByRef ppvObject As Object) As LongPtr
    #Else
        Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
                (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
                 ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
        Private Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
                (ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As Long
        Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
                (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, _
                 ByRef ppvObject As Object) As Long
    #End If
    
            
    Private Type GUID
        Data1 As Long
        Data2 As Integer
        Data3 As Integer
        Data4(7) As Byte
    End Type
    
    Private Const S_OK As Long = &H0
    Private Const IID_IDispatch As String = "{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    Private Const OBJID_NATIVEOM As Long = &HFFFFFFF0

    Sub getWorkbook(wkbName As String, counter As Long)
    
       Const MAX_TRIES As Long = 10
    
       Dim wkb As Workbook
       Set wkb = getWkb(wkbName)
       If Not wkb Is Nothing Then
           
           ' Do your Stuff here
           If Not wkb Is Nothing Then
               MsgBox "Got you: " & wkb.Name
               Windows(wkbName).Activate
           End If

           Exit Sub
       Else
           counter = counter + 1
           If counter <= MAX_TRIES Then
               Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "'getWorkbook""" & wkbName & """,""" & counter & "'"
           End If
       End If
       
    End Sub

    Private Function getXLApp(hWinXL As Long, xlApp As Excel.Application) As Boolean
        ' Function GetXLApp(hWinXL As Long, xlApp As Object) As Boolean
        
        Dim hWinDesk As Long, hWin7 As Long
        Dim obj As Object
        Dim iid As GUID
        
        Call IIDFromString(StrPtr(IID_IDispatch), iid)
        hWinDesk = FindWindowEx(hWinXL, 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
        hWin7 = FindWindowEx(hWinDesk, 0&, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
        
        If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hWin7, OBJID_NATIVEOM, iid, obj) = S_OK Then
            Set xlApp = obj.Application
            getXLApp = True
        End If
    
    End Function
    Private Function getXLApps() As Collection
        
        Dim hWinXL As Long
        hWinXL = FindWindowEx(0&, 0&, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
        
        Dim col As Collection
        Set col = New Collection
        
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
          Do While hWinXL > 0
                    
            If getXLApp(hWinXL, xlApp) Then
                col.Add xlApp
            End If
            
            hWinXL = FindWindowEx(0, hWinXL, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
        
        Loop
        
        Set getXLApps = col
        
    End Function
    Private Function getWkb(wkbName As String) As Workbook
    
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim col As Collection
        Set col = getXLApps
        Dim i As Long, xlApp As Excel.Application
        For i = 1 To col.Count
            Set xlApp = col.Item(i)
            For Each wb In xlApp.Workbooks
                If wb.Name = wkbName Then
                    Set getWkb = wb
                    Exit Function
                    
                End If
            Next
        Next i
        Set wb = Nothing
    End Function

Then adjust your code like that
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").SelectedRows = ""
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").ContextMenu
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").SelectContextMenuItem "&XXL"
session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press
filname = "Reuse_" & Date & Hour(Now) & ".xlsx"
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxt[1]").Text = filname
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxt[1]").CaretPosition = 7
session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press

'Windows(filname).Activate
getWorkbook filename, 0

In the sub getWorkbook I added the part where you can do your stuff, see below the comment in the code. And you need to do it there because you also need to do it asynchronously.
' Do your Stuff here
If Not wkb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Got you: " & wkb.Name
    Windows(wkbName).Activate
End If

